# Cannot find the declaration of element 'custom-objects'

Tags: custom-object, marketing-cloud-connect, commerce-cloud, b2c

I have been adhering to the guidelines provided on the SFMC Connector repository, and as per one of the instructions, it is recommended to "import the metadata, custom objects, and job definitions into your B2C Commerce environment." While I was able to successfully import the Custom Object Type definitions, I encountered an error while importing one of the custom objects. The error message states "ERROR [2|86] cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'custom-objects'." I would like to know if anyone has faced a similar issue and found a solution for it.